# Work visa rejected twice

Tags: working-visas, schengen, malta

I wanted to share my recent experience with my work visa application to Malta through the Maltese embassy in Tunisia. I secured a job offer in the tourism sector from a Maltese employer and submitted my application via VFS. However, things took an unexpected turn.

I was contacted by the consulate for an interview, but I had to miss it as I was waiting for a recent experience certificate from my employer, a requirement by the consulate. When I contacted the embassy to reschedule the interview, I was told by the consulate, "When we need you, we will call you." Despite my efforts, I did not receive any feedback, so I went ahead and attended the interview later.

During the interview, I provided inaccurate information about the payment details related to my job contract with a local agency and the payment for the work permit. As a result, my application was rejected, citing "reasonable doubts as to the reliability of the statements made."

I've been trying to reach out to the consulate to express my sincere apologies and explain my situation. However, I have not received any response, except being advised to file an appeal and refrain from calling the consulate's personal number.

I'm concerned that my actions may affect future visa applications, and I wonder if a new job offer from my Maltese employer would be accepted by the Maltese embassy. I'm seeking insights and advice on how to navigate this situation.

Thank you.

Edit: When I mentioned I have provided inaccurate information, it was verbally during the interview. I did not mention my payements to an agency.

Comment: It all depends on *I provided inaccurate information*. We have no idea on how to assess that. Note: the visa refusal may hints they didn't interpret it as a genuine error but as an intentional fraud. (Note: they do interviews several times every days, so they are constantly trained, also note: Malta is in Schengen area, so information are shared with many other countries).

Comment: Please edit the question to give more details about what you mean by "provided inaccurate information". Did you get the date of a previous job wrong by a few months? Or did you invent a fictitious educational qualification? Or something between those?

Comment: inaccurate information: When the consulate officers asked me if I have made payments for the work permit and an agency fees I've lied about it, responding the their inquiry how I got to know my employer. Note: Most applicants who apply through agency will lie about it and tel the embassy staff that they find a job through applying online.

Comment: Generally visa officers don't like people lying to them. Lying is very likely to put you on a banned list.

Comment: @Ahmed2024 Please edit that information into the question. Also, is your job actually genuine? Or did you pay somebody to write you a job offer with the intention that you never actually do that work once you got to Malta?

Comment: Noted. As mentioned, I have dealt with an agency, I was interview by a Maltese employer in face to face interview before online interviews with direct managers. Also the agency checks our certificates and work experiences.  I just paid fees for the work permit and the agency fees. The latter told me not to mention their payment during the interview visa at the embassy. Which,  I did. My job is restaurant server.

Comment: They may have told you that it was a genuine job offer, but that doesn't necessarily mean it was. They got your money - the "agency fee".

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on Expatriates Stack Exchange, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 licence](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts will result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your post being [locked](//expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts).

Answer (score 3):

One of the most frequently used immigration scams is where somebody from the destination country (Malta in your case) agrees to provide you with a "job offer" that the immigrant candidate can use to obtain a work visa. In return they expect to be paid a fee (that's the "Agency Fee" in your case). It's understood that the immigrant candidate won't actually have to do the job, and won't be paid for it. The job doesn't actually exist. Real employers do not require a fee up front in order to make a job offer. That is why the agency told you to lie at the interview. This was bad advice.

It's so frequently used that immigration officials are very much aware of it and it usually isn't successful. That doesn't worry the offering "company" because they already have their fee by then. However the candidate is now marked as having attempted fraud to get a visa. This will usually mean the candidate gets a legal ban on future immigration for some time. If it doesn't then it means that all future visa applications will be scrutinised very carefully and will attract a huge amount of skepticism.

Your application has all the hallmarks of this kind of fraud. The fact that you had to pay a fee is a key indicator. The fact that they realised you had lied probably means they were aware that this agency doesn't make genuine job offers. It will be almost impossible for you to ever get a visa of any kind for a Schengen country for many years, and probably also for many countries that deal with them. It is virtually certain that a future application involving this agency will be rejected.

It doesn't actually matter whether this was a genuine job offer or not.  All that matters is that Maltese Immigration think it was fake.

Comment: Why ban forever sir? I did only a verbal mistake during a visa interview. Are you sure about your informations?

Comment: It may not be a permanent ban.

Comment: @Ahmed2024 DJClayworth is exactly correct: a consciously false statement made by a visa applicant during a visa interview will not be perceived by any visa officer as a "mistake." It will be perceived as lying.